# How to add external url link in Magento Admin menu

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, adminhtml

I am working on a module where i created some menu in Magento admin using `adminhtml.xml`

Now i want to link one of the menu to an external url and set `target="blank"`. But i not sure how to do it in `adminhtml.xml`. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <system>
            <children>
                <convert translate="title">
                    <children>
                        <importmagmi translate="title" module="importexport">
                            <title>MagMi Importer</title>
                            <action><url helper="https://externalurl.com /></action>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        </importmagmi>
                    </children>
                </convert>
            </children>
        </system>
    </menu>
</config>
```

When i am checking its adding current domain name before external url. 
ex: http://mydomainname.com/https://externalurl.com

I am wondering how to set only external URL?

Answer (score 2):

Inside `<action>` tag you can put `module/controller/action` of your module.

Then create this action and put something like this:

```
public function locationAction()
{
    $this->_redirectUrl('http://www.example.com/');
}
```

See [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirectUrl`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L674) for the standard redirect implementation in Magento controller actions.

Comment: I write in action node "external/controller/batchurl" . `<?php

class Demo_External_Adminhtml_ExternalController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  protected function batchurlAction()
  {
    $this->_redirectUrl('http://www.example.com/');
  }
  
}` But not get the external url in the menu link.

Comment: try <<frontname>>/external/batchurl. Don't forget to replace frontname with your real frontname from config. It can be demo, external or demo_external. So you may probably get external/external/batchurl

Comment: Please provide alternate for creating controller action and giving an anchor href directly onto the menu link.